# failed to open stream: No such file or directory Warning: require_once Fatal error: require_once():

Tags: php, xampp

```
Warning: require_once(/home/kronaglobal/public_html/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\kronaglobal\index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/kronaglobal/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\kronaglobal\index.php on line 22
```

Please help if anyone know this.

Comment: That error message is pretty straightforward: you are trying to include a file that doesn't exist `/home/kronaglobal/public_html/system/startup.php`

Comment: Thanks Mickael B. Now it is working.